# Why doesn't unreal's UPEOPERTY(Replicated) tag automatically sync data from client to server?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, dedicated-server

As we known, in unreal dedicated server , the UPEOPERTY(Replicated) tag will sync change datas from server to client automatically. However, why not unreal implement such function on client side, instead of invoking rpc to change server datas?

Comment: The simple answer is: Never trust the client. Ever. The main reason, why you can replicate a property to the clients but only call RPCs to the server is security.